# One blank line in list item

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I try to write a code to fill my list item in oracle form builder.

I do it by write a function to handle this.

```
list_index number(10) := 1;

clear_list(list_item1);
FOR I IN (Select id,desc FORM table1)
LOOP
  ADD_LIST_ELEMENT('list_item1',list_index,desc,id);
  list_index := list_index + 1;
END LOOP

list_item1 := get_list_element_value('list_item1',1);
```

my result in output is like this:

```
x1
x2
x3
x4
<a blank field>
```

but in my database table I just have

```
x1
x2
x3
x4
```

would you help me please to how find what's my problem that I have one more space in my list item.

Comment: If you're going to just populate the list item from a query, you should base the list item on a record group based on the query, instead of populating it using a procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forms maintains an additional NULL element in a list item.  From the on-line help:

**List Items and Null Values** 
...
Setting the Required property for a poplist or TList may affect the values the list will display: When selected, an instance of a poplist will display an extra null value if its current value is Null or if its effective Required property is false.

**CLEAR_LIST Built-in**
Clears all elements from a list item. After Oracle Forms clears the list, the list will contain only one element (the null element), regardless of the item's Required property.

Answer (score 1):

the null value always displays in the List item........ you can solve this by going in the property pallete of the list item and setting the property name Required to YES that is by default set to NO by the oracle forms. In this way the user will not be able to insert null value into the field .

Answer (score 1):

Go To property palette of that item--> A option will show like Required--->
change the value = YES instead of NO